# perf top view disassembly without symbol (with stripped binary)

Tags: linux, performance, disassembly, perf

I'm trying to use Linux perf to do some performance analysis. I have an application that is built with symbols stripped, and I was surprise that Linux perf top could not display the disassmbly line. It only displayed the raw EIP.

How do we map the performance event back to raw assembly line without symbol info?

Comment: `perf top` gives a live overview of the profiled activity, that is not really compatible with annotated code. I mean you want extreme details on varying statistics. If you want to analyse the performance of your application, use `perf record` and then `perf report` or `perf annotate`.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can try this: 1) add '-g' in Makefile; 2) use "objdump" to dump out the mixture of source code and asm.

Comment: The first one is not an option, because I'd like to develop a methodology that works for general case. I'm currently doing the second one, but it's inefficient because I need to map each EIP manually.

Comment: @Patrick Using `-g` and having debug symbols would help ... Do you mean you want to do performance analysis within degraded conditions?